# Iterating exact triangles (particularly in Floer homology)

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, gt.geometric-topology, homological-algebra, sg.symplectic-geometry

There are several different Floer-homological invariants of 3-manifolds (and knots). The most prominent of these are Heegaard Floer homology, monopole Floer homology, and instanton Floer homology. It is now known, thanks to hundreds upon hundreds of pages of work by Taubes and others, that the first two theories are isomorphic. It remains a mystery and a major open question how these two are related to the instanton theory.

A common feature of all of these theories is the so-called *surgery exact triangle*. Given a closed, oriented 3-manifold $M$, let $H(M)$ denote its Floer homology (with respect to any of the Heegaard, monopole, or instanton theories), which we will assume takes the form of a finite-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{C}$. Let $K\subset M$ be a framed knot.
Then there is an exact triangle

$$\dots \to H(M)\xrightarrow{} H(M_0)\xrightarrow{f} H(M_1) \xrightarrow{} H(M)\to \dots$$

where $M_i$ denotes the result of $i$-surgery on $K$ with respect to its framing, and each of these maps is induced by a natural 2-handle cobordism. In particular, $H(M)$ is quasi-isomorphic to the mapping cone of $f$,

$$H(M) \simeq \big(H(M_0)\xrightarrow{f} H(M_1)\big).$$

Moreover, the surgery exact triangle can be *iterated* in each of these theories.

Indeed, suppose that $K = K_1\cup \dots \cup K_n$ is a framed n-component link in $M$. Given an $n$-tuple

$$I = (i_1,\dots,i_n)\in\{0,1\}^n,$$

let $M_I$ denote the result of performing $i_j$-surgery on $K_j$ for each $j=1,\dots,n$. Then $H(M)$ is quasi-isomorphic to a *hypercube* complex $(C,D)$, where

$$C = \bigoplus_{I\in\{0,1\}^n} H(M_I).$$

Let us write $I<I'$ if $I\neq I'$ and if each entry of $I$ is less than or equal to the corresponding entry of $I'$. Then a pair $I<I'$ corresponds to the diagonal of some face of the hypercube given by the convex hull of the points $\{0,1\}^n\subset \mathbb{R}^n$. In particular, edges of the cube correspond to those pairs $I<I'$ where $I'$ is obtained from $I$ by changing a single entry from 0 to 1.

The differential $D$ on the complex $C$ is then a sum of maps of the form

$$D_{I<I'}: H(M_I) \to H(M_{I'})$$

over all pairs $I<I'$. The edge maps are the natural 2-handle cobordism maps. The maps associated with diagonals of higher dimensional faces are defined in the monopole and instanton settings in terms of cobordisms equipped with higher dimensional families of metrics and perturbations. In the Heegaard Floer setting, these longer maps are defined by counting pseudo-holomorphic polygons in the symmetric product of some Riemann surface. In general, these longer maps depend on the auxiliary choice of data made in their construction (in contrast with the edge maps, which are topological invariants of the associated cobordisms).

Note that the differential $D$ is filtered with respect the *cube grading* on $C$ given by $$\textrm{gr}(H(M_I)) = |I| = i_1+\dots + i_n,$$ thus giving rise to a spectral sequence abutting to $H(M)$. This construction was first used by Ozsvath and Szabo in the Heegaard Floer setting to define a spectral sequence from the Khovanov homology of a link to the Heegaard Floer homology of its branched double cover. A similar construction in the instanton setting was a key ingredient in Kronheimer and Mrowka's proof that Khovanov homology detects the unknot.

As suggested above, the process of *iterating* these surgery exact triangles to form the hypercube complex whose homology computes $H(M)$ is highly technical and specific to the version of Floer homology in question. This motivates the following:

**Question:** Is there some purely algebraic way of iterating these surgery exact triangles, which makes no reference to cobordisms with families of metrics, say? Asked differently, suppose one knew all of the vector spaces and maps in every surgery exact triangle in their favorite Floer theory $H$. Is this enough, given a framed link $K\subset M$, to build a hypercube complex with the properties described above whose homology computes $H(M)$, via abstract nonsense?

I think the answer to the question is yes when $K$ has 2 components, but I'm not sure how to algebraically iterate beyond that.

Comment: Welcome to MO, John. Can I rephrase your question as: "Let H be your favorite Floer theory. Suppose you have a pair of n-component links L, L', and an isomorphism f: H(M_I(L)) = H(M_I(L')) for each I subset {1,...,n}, so that f D_{I < I'}(L) = D_{I < I'}(L') f for |I'| - |I| = 1. Then f D_{I < I'}(L) = D_{I < I'}(L') f for all I, I', not just the edge maps" or, as an alternate weaker conclusion "Then f induces an isomorphism between E_1 pages which commutes with all higher differentials in the spectral sequence"? I'm trying to figure out what a "no" answer would look like.

Comment: Hi Mike! Really what I'm asking is if there is some (relatively natural) algebraic rather than geometric way to define higher diagonal components, D_{I<I'}(L) for |I'|-|I|>1, so that the resulting hypercube complex computes H(M). You're allowed to use as a starting point all surgery exact triangles that exist in the theory. The vector spaces and maps in these triangles are defined geometrically, of course. The question is whether one can build the hypercube complex algebraically from those.

Comment: Put differently, we know that the surgery exact triangles in these Floer theories can be "iterated" in the manner described in my post, but only because of our various geometric, theory-specific means of defining these higher diagonal maps. Is there some algebraic feature of these Floer groups and the maps that appear in the surgery exact triangles which tells you that iteration is possible? Is there some algebraic obstruction to iterating triangles more generally which happens to vanish for the exact triangles appearing in these Floer theories? (I realize this is pretty vague.)

Comment: I think I have a good sense of what a positive answer is! But I am inclined to be cynical, so I'm wondering what kind of negative answers you would accept. That is, how would you state that such an auxiliary package for higher differentials really is necessary?